# PySpark : Optimize read/load from Delta using selected columns or partitions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I am trying to load data from Delta into a pyspark dataframe.

```py
path_to_data = 's3://mybucket/daily_data/'
df = spark.read.format("delta").load(path_to_data)
```

Now the underlying data is partitioned by date as

```
s3://mybucket/daily_data/
    dt=2020-06-12
    dt=2020-06-13
    ...
    dt=2020-06-22
```

Is there a way to optimize the read as Dataframe, given:

1. Only certain date range is needed
2. Subset of column is only needed

Current way, i tried is :

```py
df.registerTempTable("my_table")
new_df = spark.sql("select col1,col2 from my_table where dt_col > '2020-06-20' ")
# dt_col is column in dataframe of timestamp dtype.
```

In the above state, does Spark need to load the whole data, filter the data based on date range and then filter columns needed ? Is there any optimization that can be done in pyspark read, to load data since it is already partitioned ?

Something on line of :

```py
df = spark.read.format("delta").load(path_to_data,cols_to_read=['col1','col2'])
or 
df = spark.read.format("delta").load(path_to_data,partitions=[...])
```

Comment: if you call `.explain` on your query, the resulting query plan should mention a `PartitionFilter` that references your `dt` column. Can you add this query plan to your post?

Answer (score 5):

In your case, there is no extra step needed. The optimizations would be taken care by Spark. Since you already partitioned the dataset based on column `dt` when you try to query the dataset with partitioned column `dt` as filter condition. Spark load only the subset of the data from the source dataset which matches the filter condition, in your case it is `dt > '2020-06-20'`.

Spark internally does the optimization based partitioning pruning.

Answer (score 4):

To do this without SQL..

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.read.format("delta").load(path_to_data).filter(F.col("dt_col") > F.lit('2020-06-20'))
```

Though for this example you may have some work to do with comparing dates.